# In R, how can move variable list and make the plot scatterd?

Tags: r, variables, plot

[image]

I wish to change two things.

First is moving the $100,000 right.
Second is making the plot more like scatterd not just for $1~24,999 but all.
This is the code for above plot.

```
ggplot(aes(x = IncomeRange, y = AmountDelinquent), data = df_copy) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtEVH.jpg)

Please check above pic. Seems like there's a problem with arguments. But by 'table', it says there exist "$100,000+", "Not employed", "Not displayed" . and it is true. I think this is the reason your code doesn't work on my R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is that `IncomeRange` is a factor and you need to reorder the levels. You can try something like this before plotting:

```
df_copy$IncomeRange <- factor(df_copy$IncomeRange, 
                              levels = c("$0", "$1-24,999", "$25,000-49,999",
                                         "$50,000-74,999", "$75,000-99,999", "$100,000+", 
                                         "Not displayed", "Not employed"))
```

Your second issue: use `geom_jitter` instead of `geom_point`.

If you use `tidyverse`, you can alter the data non-destructively using `mutate` and pipe the result to `ggplot`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_copy %>%
  mutate(IncomeRange = factor(IncomeRange, 
                              levels = c("$0", "$1-24,999", "$25,000-49,999",
                                         "$50,000-74,999", "$75,000-99,999", "$100,000+", 
                                         "Not displayed", "Not employed"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(IncomeRange, AmountDelinquent) + 
    geom_jitter()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But with your first code chunk, the order remains same(the column names like $0, $1-24,999 are correct.) on the plot, I don't know why. Second code chunk doesn't even run.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the data in df_copy. The code works for me on example data that I generated.

Comment: I added  my question and there is an error there, if you don't mind, check it please.

Comment: Oh my goodness you are right. Really appreciate your help! =)